# Как правильно сверстать заголовок с задним фоном?

Tags: html, вёрстка, figma

Есть тег main и в нем есть заголовок(h1), но у заголовка сзади фон(только у заголовка). И я думаю по семантике лучше обернуть этот заголовок в header, но тогда если я правильно понимаю заголовок будет озаглалавлять только header, тогда получается единственный вариант обернуть его div(заголовок)?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без разницы див и хидер

Answer (score 0):

В тег header обычно размещают логотип и навигацию. Ваш h1 это уже main. Вполне нормально, если для задания фона вы h1 обернёте в div или section.

Comment: Не все браузеры при стилизации воспринимают тег хидер, лучше использовать див, его стилем проще управлять

Comment: @Arcadiy, посмотрел caniuse.com, поддержка у header 94,7%. Я бы для своих проектов не стал заморачиваться, но если требования более строгие, то, конечно, div более предпочтителен с его 98,1%.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать хоть вот так.

```css
body {margin: 0;}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: url('//i.imgur.com/raz226g.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок<br>с задним<br>фоном</h1>
```

По сути, вам никто не запрещает так делать.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно на практике верстальщики используют стили для h1-h6, p, span только визуальные (font-size, color, font-family ....)
Поэтому да, лучше завернуть его в div, а этот div в header, так как он более тяготеет к верхней части страницы.

Comment: Но ведь тогда он будет озаглавливать только header(как я понял почитав спецификацию) Или не так? "The first element of heading content in an element of sectioning content represents the heading for that section"